# How can i change the expand level of nodes in treeView1 according to numericupdown value change?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have this method:

```
void ExpandToLevel(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int level)
        {
            if (level > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
                {
                    node.Expand();
                    ExpandToLevel(node.Nodes, level - 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then inside numericupdown1 valuechanged event i'm changing the expand level according to the value.
This is working fine when i'm raising the vlaue in the numericupdown if it's 1 by default.
Then i raise it to 2 3 4 and i see the treeView1 expand more and more.
But if i move down back the value nothing happen it's stay on the same expand level.

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExpandToLevel(treeView1.Nodes, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);
        }
```

How can i make that if i change the numericupdown value back down it will epxand back the levels of nodes in the treeView1 ?

This is what i tried so far.
I added this new method:

```
void CollapseToLevel(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int level)
        {
            if (level > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
                {
                    node.Collapse();
                    CollapseToLevel(node.Nodes, level - 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then in the numericupdown value changed event i changed the code to:

```
decimal oldValue;
        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (numericUpDown1.Value > oldValue)
            {
                ExpandToLevel(treeView1.Nodes, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                CollapseToLevel(treeView1.Nodes, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);
            }
            oldValue = numericUpDown1.Value;

        }
```

When i expand change the numericupdown value up it's expand it fine level by level.
But when i collapse it back when changing the numericupdown value back down if i was at value 4 and now changed to value 3 all the nodes collapsed back to root.

I want it to collapse only by one level from 4 to 3 to 2 to 1 when the vlaue is 0 then collapse back to root.

The collapse is not working good.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExpandOrCollapseToLevel(treeView1.Nodes, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);
}

void ExpandOrCollapseToLevel(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int level)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (level > 0)
            node.Expand();
        else
            node.Collapse();
        ExpandToLevel(node.Nodes, level - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: IAfanasov your solution is working good when expand it. Each time i raise up the value it does expand by one level. But if i collapse it back only when i'm getting to value 0 it's collapsing it all to root. I want that when i change the value back down one by one it will collapse it back one level each time untill root.

Comment: I mean if i expanded it to value 3 meaning 3 levels so i will be able now to collapse it back only one level from 3 to 2. Now it will collapse it all at once when i change the value to 0 before it it will not do anything.

Comment: @JorgeHyyest I hope I get you (: What I get is you want to collapse only one level whatever value user choice in UpDown?

Comment: Yes one level each time up or down value change. If i changed the value from 1 to 2 expand by one level if i changed the value from 2 to 1 back collapse one level back. The expand is working fine the collapse is not it should be also one level each value change.

Comment: sounds like UpDown control raises ValueChanged event only then focus is moved from UpDown. Not in the actual moment of changing value. Check it with debugger. If it's the issue try to use other event of UpDown. OnClick or OnButtonPressed looks like suitable ones.